# copying MOF file to vhd (xvhdFile) before boot

Tags: powershell, dsc

I'm working on a lab DSC build on a single server. I have a mof file for a server (`vhdx`) that I'm copying to `c:\windows\system32\configuraiton\pending.mof`. The idea being that at boot, the system will apply the mof and the system will be configured.

Unfortunately, the mof file isn't being copied. I have other entries under `xVhdFile` that are being copied (`unattended.xml`, `DSC resource directories`) but not the mof. Anyone know why?

Here is the `xVhdFile` entry:

```
xVhdFile "CopyUnattendedXml DC01"
{
    VhdPath =  "F:\VMs\DC01\DC01`.vhdx"
    FileDirectory =  @(

        # Pending.mof
        MSFT_xFileDirectory {
            SourcePath = 'F:\DSCScripts\Lab01\ForestRoot\Localhost.mof'
            DestinationPath = "\Windows\Sytem32\Configuration\Pending.mof" 
        }

        # unattend.xml
        MSFT_xFileDirectory {
            SourcePath = 'F:\VMs\Sysprep\2016DataCenterEval_2.xml'
            DestinationPath = "\Windows\System32\Sysprep\Unattend.xml"
        }

        # xActiveDirectory
        MSFT_xFileDirectory {
            SourcePath = 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\xActiveDirectory\'
            DestinationPath = "\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\" 
            type    = 'Directory'
            Recurse = $True
        }

        # xNetworking
        MSFT_xFileDirectory {
            SourcePath = 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\xNetworking\'
            DestinationPath = "\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\" 
            type    = 'Directory'
            Recurse = $True
        }
    )
    DependsOn = "[File]CopyBaseImage DC01"
}
```

Thanks

Verbose output:

```
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]: LCM:  [ Start  Resource ]  [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01]
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]: LCM:  [ Start  Test     ]  [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01]
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] Alias
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] C
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] Cert
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] D
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] E
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] Env
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] F
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] Function
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] H
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] HKCU
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] HKLM
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] Variable
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] WSMan
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] H:\
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] DestinationPath => \Windows\Sytem32\Configuration\Pending.mof
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] Recurse => True
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] Force => True
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] Type => File
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] Ensure => True
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] Content =>
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] SourcePath => F:\DSCScripts\Lab01\ForestRoot\Localhost.mof
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] Attributes =>
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] Testing the file with relative VHD destination
\Windows\Sytem32\Configuration\Pending.mof
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] Test returned False
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]: LCM:  [ End    Test     ]  [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01]  in 2.4530 seconds.
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]: LCM:  [ Start  Set      ]  [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01]
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] Alias
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] C
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] Cert
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] D
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] E
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] Env
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] F
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] Function
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] H
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] HKCU
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] HKLM
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] Variable
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] WSMan
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] DestinationPath => \Windows\Sytem32\Configuration\Pending.mof
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] Recurse => True
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] Force => True
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] Type => File
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] Ensure => True
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] Content =>
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] SourcePath => F:\DSCScripts\Lab01\ForestRoot\Localhost.mof
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] Attributes =>
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]:                            [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01] Setting the VHD file Copy
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]: LCM:  [ End    Set      ]  [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01]  in 1.6880 seconds.
VERBOSE: [WIN-LBCPOR4PDR5]: LCM:  [ End    Resource ]  [[xVhdFile]CopyUnattendedXml DC01]
```

Comment: Do you have the verbose log when DSC is copying the mof?

Comment: I added that section of the output. There are no errors in any of the output. One of the things I did leading up to this version was move the mof file to the top of the xVhdFile FileDirectory array. Notice how it doesn't process any of the subsequent array entries..

Comment: What operating system is the VHD?  Does it have any WMFs applied?

I think I have a workaround either way.  Copy the MOF to another location and use Start-DscConfiguration in the Unattend to run the configuration.  I'm going to be offline for a while, otherwise I'd go into more detail.

Comment: The image is a generic unchanged Server 2015 Eval. Install.wim.

Comment: Server 2016 I assume?

Comment: yes, sorry, 2016.
I've been working on this going step-by-step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo.  `Sytem32` should be `System32`.  This line:

```
DestinationPath = "\Windows\Sytem32\Configuration\Pending.mof"
```

Becomes:

```
DestinationPath = "\Windows\System32\Configuration\Pending.mof"
```

The file was being copied just not where expected.

I found this by recreating your failure and searching the VHD update by the configuration for Pending.mof (`dir F:\pending.mof -Recurse`) and saw that the folder wasn't actually the DSC configuration folder.

Comment: Yeah. After going into the belly of the Debug beast I just came up with the same thing, tested and it works now.
PEBCAK!
Thanks!

Comment: No Problem, it happens, and it's [PEBKAC](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PEBKAC).